# Laravel whereNotIn not working as subquery

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

Hello wonderful people of SO!

I have a problem that I cannot solve by myself even after searching, googling and reading through so many articles

I have 3 models:

1. `User`
2. `Food`
3. `Ingredient`

   ```
   User.php

   public function favourites()
   {    
          return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class, 'food_user', 'user_id', 'food_id', 'id', 'id');
   }`

   // Some people dislike some ingredient(s) or alergic to it
   public function dislikes()
   {
          return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class, 'ingredient_user', 'user_id', 'ingredient_id', 'id', 'id');
   }

   Food.php

   public function likes()
   {
          return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'food_user', 'food_id', 'user_id', 'id', 'id');
   }

   public function ingredients()
   {
          return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class, 'food_ingredient', 'food_id', 'ingredient_id', 'id', 'id');
   }

   Ingredient.php

   public function foods()
   {
          return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class, 'food_ingredient', 'ingredient_id', 'food_id', 'id', 'id');
   }

   public function disliked()
   {
          return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'ingredient_user', 'ingredient_id', 'user_id', 'id', 'id');
   ```

}

So after setting these relationships, now I want to implement search system

```
SearchController.php

use ...
use ...

public function foods(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::with(['dislikes'])->find(x);

    $dislikes = $user->dislikes->pluck('pivot')->pluck('ingredient_id')->toArray();

    $query = $request->query('keyword');

    $builder = Food::query()->with(['ingredients']);

    $builder->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%");

    $builder->orWhereHas('ingredients', function ($query) use ($dislikes) {
        // This is not working, it STILL fetch all food with ingredients the current user dislikes
        $query->whereNotIn('ingredient_id', $dislikes);
    });

    $foods = $builder->get();

    return ...
}
```

Any idea why `whereNotIn()` not working inside `orWhereHas()` clause?

Thanks in advance

Comment: dd($dislikes) what you get

Comment: Ids of disliked ingredient(s): `[3, 7, 10]`

Comment: okay.ley me analyze your query again.since its look good

Comment: try orWhereHas to whereHas

Comment: orWhereHas will become optional so it chooses all

Comment: If i understand correctly, `orWhereHas` fetch all corresponding records with / without it (CMIW), and the other side `whereHas`, fetch all corresponding records that has related to it

Comment: since you have ->with(['ingredients']) it will return all

Comment: Okay, let me test it

Comment: $builder = Food::query()->with(['ingredients'=>function ($query) use ($dislikes) {
        
            $query->whereNotIn('ingredient_id', $dislikes);
        }]);
    

    $builder->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%");
    

    $foods = $builder->get();

Comment: if its not working still you can try $builder = Food::query()->when(count($dislikes),function ($q) use ($dislikes){
        $q->whereHas('ingredients',function ($query) use ($dislikes) {

            $query->whereNotIn('ingredient_id', $dislikes);
        });
    });
   


    $builder->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%");


    $foods = $builder->get();

Comment: it's working and give me expected result

Any rules / regulation I have to follow? **I never learn SQL**, since I'm from front-end

Comment: just print qurey if its not working then you get some idea which case is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your query since with will return all result issrespective of condition in your case

```
$builder = Food::query()->with(['ingredients'=>function ($query) use ($dislikes) {
     $query->whereNotIn('ingredient_id', $dislikes);
     }]); 
    $builder->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%"); 
    $foods = $builder->get();
```

you can can use callback inside with relation or you can use when callback like below

```
$builder = Food::query()->when(count($dislikes),function ($q) use ($dislikes){
 $q->whereHas('ingredients',function ($query) use ($dislikes) {
 $query->whereNotIn('ingredient_id', $dislikes);
 }); 
}); 
$builder->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%"); 
$foods = $builder->get();
```

Comment: @ChristianDelvianto.no issues .glad that you have solved your issu

Answer (score 1):

Replace orWHereHas by WhereHas since you use whereNotIn

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, but i'm afraid you are late, i'm sorry